# onscroll() to open a new tab without pop-up alert

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to open a new tab when a user is scrolling in my website.

The problem is, as far as i understand, that in order for a new tab to open automatically without a pop-up warning from the browsers, the user must first trigger an event in the DOM but apparently `onscroll()` does not count as one.

Is there a way for me to trigger an even when a user is scrolling in my website that will allow me to open a new tab without the pop-up alert from the browser?

This is currently my code:

```
window.onscroll = function(ev) {
    if(clicked === 1) {
        return false;
    }

    clicked = 1;
    var win = window.open('<?php echo $redirect ?>', '_blank');
    win.focus();
};
```

Comment: Er, why do you want to open a new tab when someone scrolls?

Comment: Even if it was possible (what I don't think), this would annoy the user. Avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

That is native browser functionality and its a good one.
Just imagine if every site could pollute your browser with a number of tabs.

For it to work the user has to accept and allow popups from your domain